# Installing the Festival Speech Synthesis System with Mavericks

Tags: macos, applications, install, text-to-speech

I am trying to install [Festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) onto my Macbook Pro running Mavericks. I tried installing it on my own, but that didn't work.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any up-to-date instructions out there on how to do this properly.  There are [these dated instructions from 2007](http://stanford.edu/~clunis/festival_macbook.html), and [these slightly less dated instructions from 2011](http://linguisticmystic.com/2011/07/15/using-festival-tts-on-os-x/), but neither worked for me.

When I [download the 4 different packages](http://festvox.org/packed/festival/2.1/) I need and then try to use the less dated instruction set, I run into this error (along with some other warnings) with GCC 4.9:

```
../include/EST_String.h:576:16: error: friend declaration specifying a default
      argument must be a definition
    friend int fcompare(const EST_String &a, const EST_String &b, 
               ^
../include/EST_String.h:579:16: error: friend declaration specifying a default
      argument must be a definition
    friend int fcompare(const EST_String &a, const char *b,
```

So I go into the source code and change the declarations where it sets `const unsigned char *table=NULL` within the function call and remove the `=NULL`.  I then keep compiling and run into this error:

```
../include/EST_TIterator.h:292:7: error: no matching function for call to
      'begin'
```

Can someone provide a complete instruction set on how to install Festival onto a more recent version of OS X? I have Homebrew 0.9.5 if it helps.

Comment: what is happening, when you say it did not work, any error messages ? did you look in the console log? it says it supports 10.6?

Comment: did you contact robert@cstr.ed.ac.uk

Comment: @Buscar웃 Upon the using the less dated instructions, I do what they say as the first fix.  I then run into a few compiler problems which I go into the source and fix so it will compile.  Then I run into the compiler problem `error: no matching function for call to 'begin'`.  I'm not sure how I would fix that one.  And no, I have not contacted Robert.

Comment: OK, please list details in your question so we do not waist time in comments, like Mac Ports version installed (2.2.1) etc....

Comment: @Buscar웃 Added all of that information.  Let me know if you would like any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an email reply I got from Rob Clark (one of the creators of Festival):

> Use the [speech_tools](http://data.cstr.ed.ac.uk/robert/protected/speech_tools-2.3-current.tar.gz) and [Festival](http://data.cstr.ed.ac.uk/robert/protected/festival-2.3-current.tar.gz) packages, then
>   unpack and run make in each directory.
>
> You will also need [dictionary and voice packages](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/download.html) from the standard download site.
>   The festvox and festlex packages should be unpacked in the directory
>   above festival (i.e. where you unpacked the festival package itself)
>
> Regards. Rob Clark.

Since Rob responded to my email with in hours, feel free to contact him for more information if needed robert@cstr.ed.ac.uk

As mentioned in the comments, unpack the festvox and festlex packages with the command line, and not the Mac's default unpacking software.

Comment: Everything worked very nicely with this solution.  I would like to mention to unpack the festvox and festlex packages with the command line, and not the Mac's default unpacking software.

Answer (score 1):

Following the release of Edinburgh Speech Tools 2.4 (on 12/25/2014), it's now possible to install that package through [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
$ brew install speech-tools
```

No formula for Festival itself yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother using Festival when you have Dictation & Speech System Preferences ? And using Automator you my create a service (& contextual) menu item to "Save the synthesised version"...

However have you installed XQuartz ?
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
Consider using a virtual box or else to get an old operating system running on your latest Mac.

After further investigations :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221650/error-in-building-speech-tools-for-festival2-1-under-gcc-in-mac-osx-10-8-5

With

> gcc --version
>   Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
>   Thread model: posix

I have the same error as you while compiling speech_tools.

Error I don't get using GCC 4.7 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/20

Hope it helps and you'll provide the 10.9 missing manual for Festival.

Comment: I would downvote this if I had the reputation. My reasons are really my own, but if you must know, I need to access to a portable speech synthesis API. The option you suggest does not offer that.

Comment: This is fair enough and indeed a good reason to get a headache  and not using Apple tools. While investigating about your question I was surprised you wanted to use a more than "3 years old" un-updated software...

Answer (score 0):

For macbook pro with Sierra High OS, this link perfectly worked for me [festival-mbrola](https://github.com/pettarin/setup-festival-mbrola)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.